# Opening a window that has no title bar with Win32

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, win32gui

I'm developing a C++ application for Windows. I'm using the Win32 API. How can I open a window without a title bar (without controls, icon and title) and that can not be resized.

The piece of code that I am using for the application to create a window:

```
hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, 0, (WS_BORDER),
                    0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

To do this in C#, you just define this code:

```
 FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
 ControlBox = false;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, 0, (WS_BORDER ), 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL); 

SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, 0); //remove all window styles, check MSDN for details

ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW); //display window
```

Comment: that does remove the title bar, but removes the border also, even if i do setWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_BORDER);

Comment: Do you want to have border but don't have title? There is no way to do it.

Comment: if it is possible in .NET (c#) than it is possible in win32 (c++). A example app would be system volume (windows7)

Comment: SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_SIZEBOX);  does the trick, now the problem is when the window is created it isn't properly painted. If i add a menu to it it will properly render when the window is resized..

Comment: SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_BORDER | WS_THICKFRAME); SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 100, 50, SWP_FRAMECHANGED); //some trick to redraw window ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

Comment: it worked! thank you. update your answer and i will accept it. Btw do you happen to know how i would prevent resizing the window and changing the cursor to the resize cursor (in c# i just ignored WM_NCHITTEST message, in c++ it's a little more complicated)

Comment: You are correct, just ignore WM_NCHITTEST message in window procedure, you can define your own window procedure in RegisterClass function, or override it after CreateWindow via SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, YourNewWindProc)

Comment: `SetWindowLong` could be easily removed. You can use 0 instead of `WS_BORDER` but probably you want `WS_POPUP` style because 0 means `WS_OVERLAPPED`. As mentioned in the comments above, add `WS_THICKFRAME` style to get the sizing border around window, otherwise no visible border is displayed around the window.

Answer (score 5):

```
HWND hWnd ;
hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, 0, (WS_BORDER ), 0, 0, 100, 100, NULL, NULL, Instance, NULL); 
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_BORDER );  // With 1 point border
//OR
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, 0 );  // Without 1 point border = white rectangle 
SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 150, 100, 250, 250, SWP_FRAMECHANGED); 

if (!hWnd)
 return FALSE ;
else
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation, or links to documentation?

Answer (score 2):

We use the following instruction:

```
hWnd = CreateWindow(
    "Example", "Example No Title Bar", 
     WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
     0, 0, myWindowWidth, myWindowHeight, 
     NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

**Output:** Window without *title bar* ***and*** not resizable

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Omit the `WS_BORDER` style:

See 
CreateWindow function:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Window Styles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: if i omit WS_BORDER a put 0 instead, the control buttons (close,minimize,maximize) and the title doesn't display, but the title bar area is still visible(where the buttons and text is), i would like to hide it also.

Answer (score 1):

```
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Too bad this got voted down. It is the correct answer. Why? Because the vendor says so - try reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles . In case the link dies, try "WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW" in your search window and read the documentation.

In my case I wanted a floating window without border or title. And...that's exactly what WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW does. I use CreateWindowExand specifying WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW for the dwExStyle parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
CreateWindowEx(0, szWindowClass, 0, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_POPUP, 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

using **`SetWindowLong`** will change the size and post. use the **`WS_POPUP`** style