# Prevent window movement

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I currently have a small game which runs in a win32 window. I just noticed that when I hold the top of the window (the bar which has the closing button) it freezes my application. I would like to disable this as it manages to completely destroy my application (timers continue to count).

It seems that with even the most minimalistic settings for creation of the window it still has this feature. How can I disable this? I currently have:

```
 HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW( L"Game",L"Game",
                          0x00000000L | 0x00080000L,
                          wr.left,
                          wr.top,
                          wr.right-wr.left,
                          wr.bottom-wr.top,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          wc.hInstance,
                          NULL );
```

I read that my thread is ignored while dragging, if I am forced into using 2 threads could someone please provide a small example of usage?

Or should I stop the timers? (what message should I catch, and would it even be catched?)

**Update**

I am using instances of my time class to handle timings which looks something like:

```
Timer::Timer() {
    __int64 frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency( (LARGE_INTEGER*)&frequency );
    invFreqMilli = 1.0f / (float)((double)frequency / 1000.0);
    StartWatch();
}

void Timer::StartWatch() {
    startCount = 0;
    currentCount = 0;
    watchStopped = false;
    QueryPerformanceCounter( (LARGE_INTEGER*)&startCount );
}
```

My Win32 message loop contains: mousemove, keyup and keydown.

Comment: If you are using `WM_TIMER` then that is a low priority pseudo-message that you'll only get when there are no other messages in your thread's message queue. Can you post some more code - like your message loop and WndProc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the title bar to the user that he/she can move the window, you could remove that title bar and borders altogether. See "[opening a window that has no title bar with win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442939/opening-a-window-that-has-no-title-bar-with-win32)" for an example.

When the game launches or is paused, you could show your own UI elements to allow the user to move the game window in these specific situations but only then.

Answer (score 2):

When DefWindowProc handles WM_SYSCOMMAND with either SC_MOVE or SC_SIZE in the wParam, it enters a loop until the user stops it by releasing the mouse button, or pressing either enter or escape. It does this because it allows the program to render both the client area (where your widgets or game or whatever is drawn) and the borders and caption area by handling WM_PAINT and WM_NCPAINT messages (you should still receive these events in your Window Procedure).

It works fine for normal Windows apps, which do most of their processing inside of their Window Procedure as a result of receiving messages. It only effects programs which do processing outside of the Window Procedure, such as games (which are usually fullscreen and not affected anyway).

However, there is a way around it: handle WM_SYSCOMMAND yourself, resize or move yourself. This requires a good deal of effort, but may prove to be worth it. Alternatively, you could use setjmp/longjmp to escape from the Window Procedure when WM_SIZING is sent, or Windows Fibers along the same lines; these are hackish solutions though.

I solved it (using the first method) this past weekend, if you're interested I have released the code to the public domain on sourceforge. Just make sure to read the README, especially the caveat section. Here it is: https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32loopl/

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the size/move loop using the [`WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WM_EXITSIZEMOVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages.