# Prevent Win32 from drawing classic title bar

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, aero, dwm

I wanted to add a nice shadow to my borderless form, and the best way I found to do it with minimal performance loss is to use [DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, this seems to be causing Windows to draw a classic title bar over the window, but it is non-functional (ie. the glitch is merely graphical).

[image: Windows Title Bar]

This is the code I am using:

```
int v = (int) DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY.DWMNCRP_ENABLED;
NativeApi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, DwmWindowAttribute.NCRENDERING_POLICY, ref v, sizeof(int));
int enable = 0;
NativeApi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, DwmWindowAttribute.ALLOW_NCPAINT, ref enable, sizeof(int));
MARGINS margins = new MARGINS() {
    leftWidth = 0,
    topHeight = 0,
    rightWidth = 0,
    bottomHeight = 1
};
NativeApi.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Handle, ref margins);
```

I have tried setting `ALLOW_NCPAINT` to 1, and I even tried returning 0 when the window receives `WM_NCPAINT` without calling `DefWndProc`, but it made no difference.

Is there a way to resolve this weird issue while still using `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442939/opening-a-window-that-has-no-title-bar-with-win32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big thanks to @Erik Philips, I have finally resolved the issue by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7443081/5007383)'s advice. The issue was in `CreateParams`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the parameters that define the initial window style.
/// </summary>
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        if (!DesignMode) {
            cp.ClassStyle |= (int) ClassStyle.DoubleClicks;
            cp.Style |= unchecked((int) (WindowStyle.Popup | WindowStyle.SystemMenu | WindowStyle.ClipChildren | WindowStyle.ClipSiblings));
            cp.ExStyle |= (int) ExtendedWindowStyle.Layered;
        }
        return cp;
    }
}
```

The `|` had to be removed from `cp.Style`:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        if (!DesignMode) {
            cp.ClassStyle |= (int) ClassStyle.DoubleClicks;
            cp.Style = unchecked((int) (WindowStyle.Popup | WindowStyle.SystemMenu | WindowStyle.ClipChildren | WindowStyle.ClipSiblings));
            cp.ExStyle |= (int) ExtendedWindowStyle.Layered;
        }
        return cp;
    }
}
```

This solved the issue, as apparently WinForms adds `WS_BORDER` by default to the class style, even if `FormBorderStyle` is later set to `None`.