# How to remove the white margin at the top of the window in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, electron

I want to remove the titlebar of winform,like electron frameless window. By adding the following code, the titlebar is removed, but there is a blank bar at the top of the window. How can I remove this blank bar?

[image]

```
private void InitializeComponent(){
            ControlBox = false;
}
```

[image]

Electron frameless window can completely remove the titlebar,

Comment: Does setting `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None` give you the result you're after?

Answer (score 0):

The `ControlBox` doesn't remove the title bar from the window. Instead, you need to use the following code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
}
```

The border style of the form determines how the outer edge of the form appears. In addition to changing the border display for a form, certain border styles prevent the form from being sized. For example, the `FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog` border style changes the border of the form to that of a dialog box and prevents the form from being resized. The border style can also affect the size or availability of the caption bar section of a form.

If that solution doesn't suit your needs you may consider using Windows API functions such as [SetWindowLong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga) which changes an attribute of the specified window. See [Opening a window that has no title bar with Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442939/opening-a-window-that-has-no-title-bar-with-win32) for more information.

Comment: If so, the size of the form cannot be changed, and the shadow outside the form is lost.

Comment: In that case you need to use Windows API setting up a windows style, for example, take a look at the `SetWindowLong` function.

Comment: Use `SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_STYLE, 0); ` ，Same as `FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`