# How to remove the titlebar & buttons from Windows win32 app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am working on a cross platform app in Flutter and I want to launch an app with a translucent background without title bar and without the window control buttons. In the bottom right corner of the screen.

It seems to work well but when launching the app it will first show an border and title bar. Then when I start to resize the window it will look like I intended.

This is the code I used for the effect:

```cpp
HWND window = CreateWindow(
     window_class, title.c_str(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
     Scale(origin.x, scale_factor), Scale(origin.y, scale_factor),
     Scale(size.width, scale_factor), Scale(size.height, scale_factor),
     nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), this);

// Hide the window control buttons (minimize, maximize, close)
SetWindowLong(window, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(window, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);

// Hide the window titlebar
SetWindowLong(window, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(window, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION);
```

And this is what it looks like when the app launches:

[image]

This is how I want the app to launch (after resizing, it will look like this):

[image]

Comment: This is probably answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442939/opening-a-window-that-has-no-title-bar-with-win32)

Comment: Also you don't want to be using `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` as that includes `WS_CAPTION` , `WS_SYSMENU` ,`WS_THICKFRAME` etc.. you could proably replace with just the minimal `WS_POPUP`

Comment: Hi @user20716902,
I have tried that as well, but the problem is: the corners are not rounded (Windows 11) and I want it to have a look and feel like the rest of Windows 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be specifying *only* the styles you actually want in the `CreateWindow()` call itself, rather than *removing* the unwanted styles after the window has been created.

For instance, you could do:

```
CreateWindow(..., WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~(WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION), ...);
```

which is identical to:

```
CreateWindow(..., WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, ...);
```

But, since `WS_SYSMENU` is not being used, you can then omit the 2 `WS_...BOX` styles:

```
CreateWindow(..., WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_THICKFRAME, ...);
```

And, since you are disabling the title bar anyway, you don't really want `WS_OVERLAPPED` (which has a title bar), so you should likely be using `WS_POPUP` instead, as 
[@user20716902 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76165321/how-to-remove-the-titlebar-buttons-from-windows-win32-app#comment134319549_76165321):

```
CreateWindow(..., WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME, ...);
```

Comment: I have tried what you & @user20716902 mention, however, using `WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER` will result in a non translucent & square box. But I want a border radius and a transparent background...  So do you know how to add them?

Comment: I think it works! I added the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` to the input making it: ```CreateWindow(
      window_class, title.c_str(), (WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_EX_APPWINDOW),
      Scale(origin.x, scale_factor), Scale(origin.y, scale_factor),
      Scale(size.width, scale_factor), Scale(size.height, scale_factor),
      nullptr, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), this);``` and that creates the desired window (rounded, translucent and without title / buttons)

Comment: @LauDijksterhuis `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` is an *extended* window style (hence the `EX`), you can't use extended styles with `CreateWindow()`, you need to use `CreateWindowEx()` instead. However, `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` has the same numeric value as `WS_THICKFRAME`, so what you are really doing is: `CreateWindow(..., WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_THICKFRAME, ...);` I have updated my answer.